When using Workbook_BeforeClose, if there is no pop-up message, the code doesn't run as expected. (EXCEL 2016)
I am creating an excel sheets for one program, and it's important to have lots of data validation cells for the client. The number of dropdown values is so huge, that when I don't delete them, after reopening the file, the table stops being table, and all the dropdowns on that sheet disappear with a message, that the file has been corrupted and needs recovery.
I decided to run a little code to delete all huge dropdowns(data validations) during the closing of the workbook. The problem is that when I close it without prior saving it, the pop-up window appears, and whenever i save it, all dropdowns disappear (as expected).
However, when i save it prior to pressing "X", there is no pop-up and the application closes instantly. I am okay that there is no pop-up, but I guess the application doesn't finish the code inside BeforeClose, cause on the next opening of the file, it's corrupted, cause of dropdowns.
Is my interpretation of the problem correct? And how to fix it? And why in the first place dropdowns cause the file to be corrupted?

Are drop-down lists based on cell ranges or on delimited texts?

I created my own custom function, which takes the range of cells, concat them and assigns that list to the cell validation function. Sooo, technically it's based on cell-ranges, but there is delimited text in the data validation list

For text-based lists, Excel has a length limit of 255 characters. This limit does not apply to VBA, but once a file with such lists is saved, Excel cannot open it anymore. Therefore, before saving the file, you need to delete the lists and recreate them after saving. Also delete before closing the file, and recreate after opening.

Great! That's actually the first time I've heard about this limit! But do you know why the deletion of those lists in BeforeClose doesn't finish? If there is no "Want to save" window, it doesn't delete all the lists

You would have to follow it carefully in steps, but if you follow the Before_Close procedure and save the file as part of this procedure, then before that the procedure deletes the lists and you save the file without these lists. On the other hand, if you save earlier, without deleting the lists, the file will be saved, the Before_Close procedure sees that the file is saved and cosiders it's OK, while the file is saved with lists and then it can't be opened.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Ohhhhh, makes sense! Well, as soon as I will come back to the task, going to make some adjustments. Thanks a lot!
